# IE7 randomly deletes <li> opening and closing tags

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, html-lists

IE7 deletes a  tag and randomly places another one a few lines after the  tag. This makes zero sense to me haha. Hopefully someone understands the workings of old IE better than me. Thanks for helping!

Here is the actual code:

```
<LI><LABEL>Comments (extra card readers, other questions, etc.) </LABEL><TEXTAREA></TEXTAREA></LI>
</UL>
<TABLE style="MARGIN-TOP: -15px">
  <TBODY>
    <TR>
      <TD><LABEL>By clicking on the submit button below, you warrant that you understand and agree to the terms and conditions of the Merchant Service Agreement.</LABEL></TD>
      <TD><INPUT id=terms type=checkbox name=terms></TD>
      <TD class=status></TD>
   </TR>
 </TBODY>
</TABLE>
<INPUT class=submit value=Submit type=submit name=Submit jQuery1287759194812="2">
</FORM>
<DIV class=clr></DIV>
```

...but IE renders it like this:

```
<LI><LABEL>Comments (extra card readers, other questions, etc.) </LABEL><TEXTAREA></TEXTAREA>
<UL></UL>
<TABLE style="MARGIN-TOP: -15px">
  <TBODY>
    <TR>
      <TD><LABEL>By clicking on the submit button below, you warrant that you understand and agree to the terms and conditions of the Merchant Service Agreement.</LABEL></TD>
      <TD><INPUT id=terms type=checkbox name=terms></TD>
      <TD class=status></TD>
   </TR>
 </TBODY>
</TABLE>
<INPUT class=submit value=Submit type=submit name=Submit jQuery1287759194812="2">
</FORM>
<DIV class=clr></DIV>
</LI>
```

Comment: Quirks mode, by any chance? Do you have a valid DOCTYPE?

Comment: "Renders" how? Where do you get that rendered output from?

Comment: Usually means that your HTML is broken somewhere. From the empty <ul> looks to me like you haven't got the opening <ul>.

Comment: @Pekka open "view source" in IE and it gives you the IE-rendering not the "original", at least in IE6 if I remember correctly.

Comment: The problem with the html might be much higher up in the page and IE finally tries to handle it when it sees the </UL>.  There could be an unmatched quote, or unmatched <LI> anywhere above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [W3 validator tool](http://validator.w3.org/) to ensure your markup is correct. You pasted a snippet with not even an opening `<ul>` so I'm hesitant on even trying that out.

Chances are you have invalid HTML and it gets treated as such.

Comment: Haha please give me a bit more credit. There is an opening ul tag, that's the just last li in a long list

Comment: How am I supposed to know what you have? Do you want me to start assuming things? Not posting the entire code makes me assume, I don't really want to assume you have it because it's possible people make technical errors, therefore I suggest pasting the real code or linking to it.

Answer (score 1):

W3 helped me to see that IE doesn't like div containers inside ul's. Switched them over to ul's inside ul's and it started working.

Comment: Only `li` s can be children of `ul` s. `div` s are fine within lis.

Comment: +1 to @jetlej for pointing out that IE won't let `UL`s have `DIV` children. +1 to @meder for pointing out that even `UL` isn't a proper child. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

It's called normalization. It's an IE7 and IE8 thing that it does with li tags. The only thing that remains in the page is the final /li tag and all others are removed. To be honest the page still renders correctly for me (sometimes) and when you get the innerhtml of anything containing an li tag you see that they are replaced by \n\r characters.

Comment: All of the previous li tags in the list render correctly, it's only the last closing tag that is moved

Comment: Does the page still show or render correctly visually? I have had this issue before mostly in IE7 and the only way I knew about the issue was because I was using SHDocVw to hook into IE and check for elements on the page and li tags were being moved about.